# Window batch commands to detect if downloaded file exists?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, printing

I use a windows batch file that scans download folder and if it detects label.pdf it sends to local printer. This works fine most of the time but often it detects file before the file completely downloads which causes PDFtoPrinter error. Is there a way to make sure the download process is complete before attempting to detect?

```
@echo off
cls
:start
IF EXIST "C:\Users\Downloads\label.pdf" (
    echo "Found!"
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 3000> nul
    "C:\Users\Downloads\PDFtoPrinter" label.pdf "4BARCODE 4B-2054A"
 
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 10000> nul
    del "C:\Users\Downloads\label.pdf"
    
) ELSE (
    echo "it isn't here!"
)
goto start
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mechanism to check if a file is locked for exclusive access by another application.

```
@echo off
cls
:start
IF EXIST "C:\Users\Downloads\label.pdf" (
    REM check if file is locked
    2>nul (>>"C:\Users\Downloads\label.pdf" (call )) && ("C:\Users\Downloads\PDFtoPrinter" label.pdf "4BARCODE 4B-2054A") || (echo file is locked)
) ELSE (
    echo "it isn't here!"
)
Timeout /T 10
goto start
```

Comment: I can report that this code did indeed solve my problem.